# Passing Value to Javascript function via Android Menu

Tags: javascript, android, menu

I have a WebView and the it loads a html page which has javascript function in it.
The WebView has some Menu's namely, edit, refresh, next & previous.
When i press Edit, i want the javascript to do what it has to?.
When i press edit, the JS function has to show checkbox.
I am not being able to pass the value to the html page.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not clear. You want to check a checkbox in an HTML-page after you press the edit button in an android menu?
use addJavascriptInterface to pass values from javascript to java:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

or just use webview.loadUrl("Javascript:...") to let javascript do something.

Comment: Thank you mate you took a trouble to answer a question which i posted on sep 26, though i could solve my issue. Anyways i followed the same approach as you the link described, but needed to modify alot on my code. Regards.